# Simple Navigation Problem

Tags: localization, navigation

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I have integrated a Pioneer3AT mobile robot with ROS 2d navigation stack.
It's scan matches are completely correct all the time, but sometimes when i send it a navigation goal, it keeps rotating for a few seconds. specially when it is moving through a door. also the planned path for the robot is very near to the walls,
I know that there is a lots of parameters in navigation stack to solve this problems,
but i don't know which one is the right one!

Any body has experienced these kind of problems ?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/61226/simple-navigation-problem/) by [Alireza](https://answers.ros.org/users/1637/alireza/) on ROS Answers with karma: 717 on 2013-04-21

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have had some of these problems too.  I think inflation_radius and cost_scaling_factor control how "expensive" it is for the robot to go close to the walls and should keep the robot further away.  But I have had great luck with tuning them myself.

---

Originally posted by [Jon Stephan](https://answers.ros.org/users/2281/jon-stephan/) with karma: 837 on 2013-04-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0